# TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's the code:

```
const test = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('mat-form-field-infix'));
test.forEach((element) => {
    element.outerHTML = '<div class="good-day-today" style="width: 0px;"></div>'; // Please note that this line works fine!
    element.style.padding = '10px';
    element.style.borderTop = '0';
});
```

Error I get when compiled:

> ERROR in src/app/***/***.component.ts(101,21): error TS2339: Property
>   'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.
>   src/app/***/***.component.ts(102,21): error TS2339: Property 'style'
>   does not exist on type 'Element'.

How can I fix it?

I tried to remove the `Array.from...` part, tried to use `for of` and `for in`, tried `as any`, but above is the way I have to do it.

Comment: You just need to cast it as HTMLElement (`element: HTMLElement`). Not sure why you need array.from though.

Comment: `as any` or any other `as` or `any` would not be allowed :(

Comment: @ChrisW., error TS2315: Type 'HTMLCollection' is not generic.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't take the time to check anything, it's just a matter of casting though like jonas has.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You need a typecast:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('mat-form-field-infix') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>)
```

That's because `getElementsByClassName` [only returns](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/165b4bc10057e763429d44f9d4e4d70eade9a5e9/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4897) `HTMLCollection<Element>`, and `Element` does not have a `style`property. The `HTMLElement` however [does implement it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/165b4bc10057e763429d44f9d4e4d70eade9a5e9/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L6693) via it's `ElementCSSInlineStyle` extended interface.

Note that this typecast is typesafe in the way that every `Element`is either a `HTMLElement` or an `SVGElement`, and I hope that your [SVG Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) don't have a class.

Comment: I had to use [`HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=4#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YEEBOGCGBPAdAGYYgC2AFACYjACup8YU+A5vFAKIA28DTEAIVwBhLtggQActgbkA5KWxQAtIRAZSqgJbwulZVrCEtADzkBKGOJgAJACoBZADLCQXHsChbwAeUIAee2duXkYoAD5zAG4AKARoInUObGAAC3JyXVCmS2RwmABvGJgSmCy+ZmhcHnwAB2xKSkMWFBg5AEYABlqzWNKyngr8KpqAI3VKeAw7EFrWuU65WIBfaKA) to make this work.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger totally right, was busy searching the reason for having Element and HTMLElement ...

Comment: Only solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 151):

Another option is to use `querySelectorAll` and a type parameter. `getElementsByClassName` is not generic, but `querySelectorAll` is - you can just pass the type of the elements that will be selected, like this:

```
const test = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.mat-form-field-infix');
```

This doesn't require any type casting, *and* it will allow you to use `forEach` immediately, rather than converting it to an array first. (`getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, which does not have a `forEach` method; `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which *does* have a `forEach` method, at least on somewhat up-to-date browsers. To support ancient browsers too, you'll need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill), or convert it to an array first.)

If you happen to just need a single element, you can use `querySelector`, which is generic as well:

```
const elm = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.foo')!;
elm.style.padding = '10px';
```

Another benefit of `querySelectorAll` (and `querySelector`) over the many other options is that they accept CSS selector strings, which can be far more flexible and precise. For example, the selector string

```
.container > input:checked
```

will select children of `<div class="container">` which are `<input>`s and are checked.

Comment: ` as NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement>` will also work with `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 4):

A workaround could be doing something like this:

```
element["style"].padding = '10px';
element["style"].borderTop = '0';
```

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it should work, I used it multiple times :)

Comment: In this case it says: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"style"' can't be used to index type 'Node'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Node'.ts(7053)   - using eslint-plugin v 5.2.0

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could help:

```
let element = <HTMLElement> document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
```

Comment: That worked for me in the following example: `const thename = <HTMLElement> document.querySelector(".thename");`. The following alternative also worked: `const thename: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(".thename");`

Answer (score 3):

While I suspect that type casting will not cause any problems in this case, I would still avoid type casting whenever possible. In this case, you can avoid type casting with [instanceof narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing):

```
const test = Array.from(
  document.getElementsByClassName('mat-form-field-infix')
)
test.forEach((element) => {
  if (!(element instanceof HTMLElement)) {
    throw new TypeError(`Expected a object of Type HTMLElement`)
  }

  element.outerHTML =
    '<div class="good-day-today" style="width: 0px;"></div>' // Please note that this line works fine!
  element.style.padding = '10px'
  element.style.borderTop = '0'
})
```

Comment: While it's good to guard against getting potentially bad code, this check really just exists to satisfy a typescript complaint and the negative case is basically impossible. Which means you're running extra unneeded code. And if the negative case did ever occur, you silently ignore the problem. Imho it's better to cast, get an exception and get good error logging in place... but realistically this is just unused code.

Comment: I agree with you that it is not good to simply return so I updated the answer to trow an Error instead. But I disagree with you that this is better to cast. Yes, you have some unneeded code which makes the code slightly slower but this is so small that it is negligible.  But if you sometimes cast and sometimes guard, it makes it harder for inexperienced developers to acquire best practices - which is usually "guard" instead of "cast". So as simple rule I would say: "always use type guards instead of casting except it is not easily possible".

Answer (score 2):

When you set the outerHTML, you're destroying the original element that was there. So, your styling doesn't work.

You'll notice that if you change it to set innerHTML, your styling *does* work.

This does not do the same exact thing, but I hope it points you in the right direction.

```js
const test = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('mat-form-field-infix'));
test.forEach((element) => {
    element.innerHTML = '<div class="good-day-today" style="width: 0px;"></div>'; // Please note that this line works fine!
    element.style.padding = '10px';
    element.style.borderTop = '0';
});
```

Comment: Those are different elements

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing a similar type of issue while doing

```
document.querySelectorAll(".<className>");
```

so instead of adding the style property, I simply got around it by just adding another class.

example:

```
//css file
    .<classname> {
        display: none;
      }
    .<classname>.show {
        display: flex;
      }

//ts file
elements.forEach((ele, index) => {
const errors = something.length;
if (index < errors) {
  ele.classList.add("show");
} else {
  ele.classList.remove("show");
}
```

});
};

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a way easier method:

Just create an index.d.ts file and add:

```
interface Element {
    style: CSSStyleDeclaration
}
```

Comment: But this will incorrectly tell typescript that all Elements have a style property. HTMLElement is only one type of Element.