# TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here's the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  });
  navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
  link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
   });
};
navSlide();
```

}

Error I get when compiled:

```
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Also you should be using `ViewChild` to get references to your elements, as it is the way angular intends it for you to get references to dom elements.

Comment: @MikeS. - The above is reproducible if you take the body of `navSlide` and put it in the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=4#code/ATDGHsDsGcBdgEYFcBOBzApi4BeYATcUJAWw0lgDoBHJLATwGUMAbDUWcFACgHJLk6LLwCUAbgBQICDHiQAhgDdcBIqXJVaDZmw5c+lBYoC0LAJaQA1tFGTpUOMCMAZC9ZWFiZCjToomrOycKACCLCwGRqZu0MDmtlKIqJgolPL4+ACiihqucORYfKDmoJa8ADTA3CK4AHzAAN6JIEaUxfLQ0HlUnGhobHxR8hxmOQkgAL7iiS4xlABmXJnDABbc3OZWlRb4GAAeNTj1TSCblpRw9GxpkGYk8rBmUCoABrNWAGLpGMAADJQAVliGA6P0WKAA7vIUPhYgASBo7fbAAD0wAA7MAANR-SgAZgm0Bedkm4iAA

Comment: @MikeS. - The Angular part of your comment could be the basis for a good answer, though, IMHO.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773652/ts2339-property-style-does-not-exist-on-type-element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773652/ts2339-property-style-does-not-exist-on-type-element)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` known to contain `Element`s, but not specifically `HTMLElement`s. In your case, you know that these are `HTMLElements` (specifically `HTMLLIElement`s), so you can use a type assertion saying that:

```
navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
    (link as HTMLElement).style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
});
```

But see [Mike S.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147521/ts2339-property-style-does-not-exist-on-type-element/62147629#comment109914537_62147521) - I don't do Angular, but it sounds like there's a more Angular-specific solution here.

Comment: Yep, my bad. I didn't quite read the error message. This will work, except you'll have to use the life-cycle hook `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`, as the view is only initialized then.

Comment: Great! It Works. Thanks @ T.J. Crowder

Comment: working perfectly for me. ty

Answer (score 0):

As T.J. said the NodeList returns NodeList of Element, another solution is type the QuerySelectorAll by yourself.

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.nav-links li');
```